# Function returns pointer to function that returns pointer to function

Tags: c

I am trying to create a threaded state machine where each state returns a pointer to the next state.  I have a number of state machines running so the next state of all these is stored in an array that is sequenced through to call them in a round robin fashion. So what I would like to do is:

```
pState[i] = (pState[i])();
```

I understand how to return a function pointer in general but since I need the returned pointer to be a type of function that returns a pointer to a function the recursion is confusing me. The state would look like:

```
pSatateFunc StateA(void){
// ... code ...
return StateB;
}
```

So, how do I define this so I can define the array of pointers?

Comment: I know this has been asked before but I can't find the question. But the short answer is no, you can't recursively define function pointers. But there are workarounds (simplest being, have the function return a void* which is cast to a function pointer)

Comment: Thanks, I was kind of thinking this but thought maybe I was missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly, but you can do it indirectly by introducing a `struct` type whose only member is a function pointer:

```
struct state
{
    struct state (*func)(void);
};
```

Then your functions are defined to return this type:

```
struct state StateA(void)
{
    /* ... code ... */
    return (struct state){ StateB };
}
```

Your `pstate` array would be of this type too:

```
struct state pState[N];

/* ... */

pState[i] = pState[i].func();
```